# What should i do if my PhD supervisor move to another country in my third year?

Tags: phd, advisor, academic-life

My Ph.D. supervisor just informed me that he plans to move to another country after three months and I am still a Ph.D. student (not a candidate). What should I do? Is it wise to transfer to another university?

Comment: Did you ask your supervisor?

Answer (score 2):

You have at least the following options:

1. Move along with your supervisor. This might involve getting accepted into their new university or (harder) keeping enrolled in your current one. There are also visa concerns and costs. Staying enrolled at the current university while living elsewhere also requires administrative action to enable it.
2. Choose a new supervisor at your current university, perhaps requiring a change in research direction.
3. Try to establish a co-supervisor situation with a new local supervisor and the one who is moving.
4. Move to a new university in your current country or another, possibly starting over.
5. Work remotely with the current supervisor. This is probably harder than it should be since the supervisor won't get "credit" at their new place so you might not get the help you need.

All of these involve tradeoffs of course.

Some people change universities at your stage (pre-candidacy). I did and it turned out to be a good decision.

But the first thing is to talk to your current advisor about the options. If they have a wide circle of collaborators, as some do, then they might be able to find you a place and a supervisor somewhere that will minimize the pain of a change.